# Why does this Arduino code not color-fade correctly, while the Python equivalent does?

Tags: python, arduino

I'm trying to write a program for my Arduino Uno that slowly fades through different colors with an RGB LED. The problem is, that instead of slowly fading, it quickly blinks several different colors, and then fades through just a couple colors. It then repeats this pattern, but with different colors. I wrote the Python equivalent of it, and it fades normally.

Here is the Arduino code:

```cpp
bool operation[3] = {false, true, false};

const int RLED = 11;
const int BLED = 9;
const int GLED = 10;

int rval = 1000;
int gval = 500;
int bval = 0;

void setup() {
  // Initialize the pins
  pinMode(RLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GLED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // Set whether we are adding or subtracting from the val variables
  // true is adding, false is subtracting
  if (rval >= 1000) operation[0] = false;
  else if (rval <= 0) operation[0] = true;
  if (gval >= 1000) operation[1] = false;
  else if (gval <= 0) operation[1] = true;
  if (bval >= 1000) operation[2] = false;
  else if (bval <= 0) operation[2] = true;

  // Add or subtract from the val variables, according to the bools
  if (operation[0]) rval++;
  else rval--;
  if (operation[1]) gval++;
  else gval--;
  if (operation[2]) bval++;
  else bval--;

  // Set the LED's color
  analogWrite(RLED, rval);
  analogWrite(BLED, bval);
  analogWrite(GLED, gval);
  delay(10);
}
```

Here is the Python equivalent (using a `tkinter` window instead of an LED):

```py
import time
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

rval = 1000
gval = 500
bval = 10
operation = [True, False, True]

def map(x, xmax, xmin, ymax, ymin):
    return ((ymax - ymin) / (xmax - xmin)) * x

while True:
    # Set whether we are adding or subtracting the val variables
    # True is adding, False is subtracting
    if rval >= 1000: operation[0] = False
    elif rval <= 0: operation[0] = True
    if gval >= 1000: operation[1] = False
    elif gval <= 0: operation[1] = True
    if bval >= 1000: operation[2] = False
    elif bval <= 0: operation[2] = True

    # Add or subtract from the val variables, according to the bools
    if operation[0]: rval += 1
    else: rval -= 1
    if operation[1]: gval += 1
    else: gval -= 1
    if operation[2]: bval += 1
    else: bval -= 1

    # Convert from RGB to hex. This is required to set the window's color
    rmapped = int(map(rval, 1000, 0, 255, 0))
    gmapped = int(map(gval, 1000, 0, 255, 0))
    bmapped = int(map(bval, 1000, 0, 255, 0))

    # Set the window's color
    root.config(bg="#%02x%02x%02x" % (rmapped, gmapped, bmapped))
    root.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

My question: what's the difference between the two? Why does the Arduino code not function properly, while the Python code does?

Comment: what is the analogwrite resolution of your arduino? default is 0 to 255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I thought 1024 was the maximum `analogWrite()` value for the Uno, when it was *actually* 255. The loop works perfectly; but the lights only dim correctly when the `val` variables are less than or equal to 255. When the `val` variables are higher than 255, the colors are at maximum brightness; they can't get any brighter. Hence, no color change when the `val`s are greater than 255. This is what caused the colors to flash.

To fix this, just replace all occurrences of `1000` with `255` in the Arduino code.